# Output name with pattern "%" doesn't work as expected

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a video (.ts) and capture snapshots (.jpeg) from another video (.mp4).
The conversion works well for both of them, but, the snapshot name `snap%.jpeg` doesn't change as `snap1.jpeg, snap2.jpeg` as it explained in [the ffmpeg documentation : image2](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#image2-2)

Command:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel 99 -i "C:\path\original.mp4" -an -sn -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -r 25 -f segment -segment_format ts -segment_time 10 -strftime 1 "C:\path\result\output-%H-%M-%S.ts" -vf fps=5 -q:v 1 -f image2 -updatefirst 1 "C:\path\result\snap%d.jpeg"
```

[image]

I haven't any error even with a high loglevel.. 
I tried to remove the quotes too, to put `%03d` or others, no change..

I'm working on Windows 8.1.

ffmpeg version :

```
ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enabl
e-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopu
s --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-
libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-z
lib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --e
nable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

I would never ask the community if i didn't search on internet for a long before, so, i really need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) with `-updatefirst 1`, only one image file is created and updated. Remove it.

2) `snap%.jpeg` doesn't specify a pattern since there's no expansion variable present. It should be `snap%d.jpeg`

(Also, if segment format set to `mkv`, that should be the extension as well).

```
ffmpeg -loglevel 99 -i "C:\path\original.mp4" -an -sn -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -r 25 -f segment -segment_format mkv -segment_time 10 -strftime 1 "C:\path\result\output-%H-%M-%S.mkv" -vf fps=5 -q:v 1 -f image2 "C:\path\result\snap%d.jpeg"
```

Comment: Oh.. thanks, i thought `-updatefirst 1` made the jpg encoding "verified" (it's not in the documentation) because i use a third part in my command to stream the blob to a canvas in a webpage, i was confusing about it, now its working perfectly (the other errors was a "too fast typing problem" but, good job)